# Hitting time for 2-dimensional brownian motion to hit the unit circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $\tau=\inf\{t : ||W_t||=1 \}$ for a two dimensional brownian motion $W_t$.  We want to find the expectation of $\tau$.

My attempt:  So far I know that $X_t=(W_t^1)^2+(W_t^2)^2-2t$ is a martingale and $\tau$ is a stopping time for $X_t$, so would I just say that

$0=E(X_0)=E(X_{\tau})=1-2E(\tau)$

and conclude $E(\tau)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You should probably elaborate a bit on why $E[X_0] = E[X_\tau]$, though, i.e. since $\tau < \infty$ a.s. and $|X_{t \wedge \tau}| \le 1$.